# Jssor slider does not display slides in Chrome

Tags: jssor

I have jssor slider working well in Firefox and IE. However in Chrome the image vanishes as soon as the transition completes. Then the image reappears just as the next transition begins. How do I "tell" Chrome to display the missing slide?

Answer (score 6):

Just set $HWA to false as you can see [here](https://github.com/jssor/slider/issues/136)

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem by changing:

```
<img data-u="image" style="position: absolute;"/>
```

to

```
<img data-u="image" style="position: relative;"/>
```

Comment: Right, there should be no 'style="position: absolute;"' for main image element.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that removing the link  from the image element fixes the problem along with setting the style="position: relative;" as mentioned above.

```
<div>
<a u=image href="#"><img src="../img/paint/08.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

to

```
<div>
<img src="../img/paint/08.jpg" style="position: relative;"/>
</div>
```