# Jssor slider transition is complate succes fully but the slider content could not display in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, slider, slideshow, jssor

Thanks for any advanced on this. I have jssor slider is good in Firefox and IE. However the images and title isn't working in Chrome. in Chrome the slider is displaying but the slider contents and images can not display. in summarize the slider transition is complate succes fully but the slider content could not display . I need help for this situation.

Comment: Please include minimal code to reproduce your problem - otherwise it is hard to help. JSFiddle is great for a minimal test case

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. All of the sudden Jssor Slider stopped working in Chrome but worked in other browsers. Got answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26414598/5298319

In my code, I added the **style="position: relative;"** in my  tag. It didn't work in the  tag for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: OK, so the system didn't allow me to write what was needed to answer your question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the "transform perspective(2000px)"

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on your answer? Why this is the OP issue? What he has to do to fix it?

Comment: Excuse my English, I am Brazilian and I am translating this text via google translator. I do not know exactly why this error is occurring, but packed excluding the "perspective (2000px)" line of the 1057 jssor.js file