# jssor slider images not displaying properly in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I have successfully implemented jssor slider on our website for more than a year (and love it!). Yesterday (9/3/15), my Chrome browser updated, and the slider on our website now does not function properly. (It still works fine using IE and Firefox.) The images show briefly, then the space goes blank, then show again at transition, then blank. I use the slider images as links, which do not work when the image is not showing.

I found a similar situation with a solution at: [Jssor slider does not display slides in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405256/jssor-slider-does-not-display-slides-in-chrome/26414598#26414598)  -- But the recommended solution (changing the style: position code from absolute to relative) is already done correctly in my code.

I'm not sure if it could be CSS or javascript issue. Has anyone else seen this problem?

Comment: Try refreshing your browser by pressing CTR+F5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating the jssor slider to the current version (19.0) helped resolve my problem that happened when Chrome updated to version 45. Hopefully the same will work for you.

Comment: Thanks @AaronWilliams and GeorgeHartas, updating to the latest version seems to have worked...

Answer (score 1):

When I added the code to the image tag, it still didn't work. But when I added it to the 'a' tag (I link the slides), then it worked. Give it a try. See www.cyedc.org for my site.

```
<a href="/pdf/pink-october-and-open-house.pdf" target="_blank" u="image" style="position: relative;">
<img src="/images/slider-image-pink-october.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: Another post said: "Update to my problem. We went and grabbed the latest jssor.slider.mini.js file and that resolved the issue. –"

Comment: Thanks, @GeorgeHartas - your solution half solved my problem! The image now shows in place, and doesn't disappear, but it is positioned to show half-way in the slider space, flush right (so only the left hand side of the image shows on the right half side of the slider space)... At least this has narrowed down that it appears to be a CSS issue, so I can tweak until it works.

Comment: Oops... It did not solve even half way - adding code to the 'a' tag made it so the same half-image effect appeared in IE and Firefox... Still, I see it is likely in the CSS code... I will see if I can find any changes in the latest file that you mentioned. I appreciate your response, tho.

Answer (score 1):

The bug appears to be with hardware acceleration. Simple solution is to set the following option in your jssor options (this defaults to true so may not be there already)

$HWA: false,

Author of jssor says he will remove HWA in v20

Answer (score 0):

Try add the same style from image tag in 'a' tag

```
<a style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px;" href="nov-izgled-na-avto-magazin.nspx">
...
<img u="image" src="content/images/2015/08 avgust/www.avtomagazin.com.mk +.png" style="position: absolute; top: 12px; left: 348px; width: 600px;" />
 </a>
```

In some cases adding the code style="position: absolute;" in both image and 'a' tags will be enough

Answer (score 0):

or just remove u="image" code from 'a' tag

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

a tag is the main issue.
And you can put the code **onclick=window.open("/","_self"**  instead of

my site is working well now

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by replacing jssor.slider.mini.js file with the latest one.
Just [download](http://www.jssor.com/download-jssor-slider-development-kit.html) the latest

Answer (score 0):

solution: download full pack ..
in demos-jquery folder, select and take the banner code that apear like yours.

replace on new code to match your old configuration values.

```
$FillMode: 2, ...
$AutoPlay: true, ...
$AutoPlayInterval: 4000, ...
$PauseOnHover: 1, ...
$ArrowKeyNavigation: true, ....
```

now replace IMG URLs

```
<img u="image" src="../img/1920/red.jpg" /> ... TO YOUR URL IMAGES
```

REPLACE RESPOSIBLE CODE to THIS ONE if not responsible well..

```
//responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$SetScaleWidth(parentWidth);          //parentWidth
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }

        //Scale slider immediately
        ScaleSlider();

        if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
            $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSlider);
        }
        //responsive code end
```

THAT's ALL
To see its workin: http://www.iscarly.com