# JSSOR Slider - linked slides not working in chrome 45

Tags: slider, jssor, srcset

When I add a href tag around my slides the slide sops displaying in chrome. It works in firefox and ie
links was added around image linke this:
 
I am using srcset in the image.

here is the url http://ec2-23-23-84-92.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403345/jssor-slider-images-not-displaying-properly-in-chrome-browser

Answer (score 2):

I already had 'jssor slider' current version (19.0), and the slider didn't work any more in Chrome 45.

I had to add  `style="position:relative;"`  on the link on my slider images

`<a href="../etc/page.html" title="Test" style="position:relative;"> <img u="image" src="002.jpg" title="Tooltip erste Bild" /></a>`

then it was successfull.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my Chrome issue

Comment: Slight amend, I was using captions for my slides and the above stopped then from working. However changing the style attribute to "position:absolute;" fixed the image display, and the captions.

Comment: Thanks friends. It has fixed the chrome issue.